# How to get Likes Count when searching Facebook Graph API with search=xxx

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am currently using Facebook graph api search to search posts as

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=iwatch&type=post&access_token=xxxxx
```

It returns in JSON format fields and use to include the **like:count** for a given post.

After reading the dev roadmap (https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) for changes after July 10th I am instructed to use the `summary=true` param but I have no idea how to get this to work with search?

From FB blog on roadmap.

> Removing 'count' from 'comments' Graph API connection We are removing the undocumented 'count' field on the 'comments' connection in the
>   Graph API. Please request `{id}/comments?summary=true` explicitly if
>   you would like the summary field which contains the count (now called
>   'total_count')

I have tried various combinations and searched for examples but no dice. Can anyone give me some advice on how to get the new summary=true to work within a search URL for searching posts?

Answer (score 151):

Couldn't find this in the documentation but multiple calls to the API are not necessary. You can use summary when querying a feed or multiple posts. Specify this in the fields parameter.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)
```

This will return a response like this.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      ....
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 56
      }
      ...
    }, 
    {
      ....
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 88
      }
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

This will be much faster than making individual requests for each object just to get the number of comments or likes.

Comment: Thanks a lot man..., U saved my time and also worry, Thanks a lot

Comment: great answer and to get total likes of page just call
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/

Comment: Thanks for this. Of course the Facebook API documentation is an utter travesty and never makes mention of a "summary" paramter >:( >:( >:(

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I ask how did you find out about this? If it's not documented, should we expect for it to be deprecated?

Comment: Works great for me! Thanks! I too would like to know where is documented?

Comment: Documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/likes/)  and this is not deprecated. This is in `v2.6` too

Comment: There is any reason why this work with the graph query URL and not when using the sdk (android, php, etc)? If i set /id of post/ and the parameters "fields" "/likes.limit(1).summary(true)" I don't get data. It only works with "/id of post/likes" with "summary=total_count" as params, for example

Comment: How do you set `summary=true` with an API? such as the PHP one? my request looks like this: $pageId . "?fields=feed{message,description,type,icon,link,likes{total_count}}

Comment: that you very much :) I didn't know I could put `.limit(0-9)` on the end of the fields. Now I can get more than 25 likes for each post without doing 2 calls.

Comment: How to get the access token?

Comment: For anyone using v12: "likes" is now a nonexisting field and should be labeled "reactions" (i.e. reactions.limit(1).summary(true))

Answer (score 23):

You can also get all **Posts > Comments > Likes** in a single request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<obj_id>/feed?fields=message,comments.limit(10).summary(true){message,from,likes.limit(0).summary(true)}
```

The braces are **nested requests**.

This gives the following result:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "Contents of the Post"
        "id": "123456789123456789",
        "comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "message": "Contents of the Comment",
            "from": {
                 "name": "John Doe",
                 "id": "123456789"
            },
            "likes": {
               "data": [],
               "summary": {
                  "total_count": 14,
                  "can_like": true,
                  "has_liked": false
               }
            },
       ...
```

Comment: How did you know about nested requests cant find anywhere in the documentation

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api => search for the word `nested`. Upvote if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 10):

The summary is on the likes connection of the post object

just call

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?summary=true&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX

there will be a 'summary' element with a 'total_count' field

Comment: I also see the FB document about this by setting "summary=1" to get the like count.
However, do you know how to get the like count when I get the page feeds by https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed

If I can't get the like counts while getting the feed, then I have to make individual request for each post just for the like count... is this the only way out?

Comment: yes, i believe that is the only way. Or at least the only way i found.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had to make multiple calls to the api.  I also added `limit=SOME_HUGE_NUMBER` so that it wouldn't paginate/limit the number that showed, but I'm not sure if that was necessary.

Comment: If it helps anyone. To get the likes and comment summary in feed call goes like this " https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/feed?fields=likes.limit(1).summary=true,comments.limit(1).summary=true&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 8):

To get the count of page likes you can use fan_count field.

```
search?q=xxx&fields=fan_count&type=page
```

Comment: to get the count of page likes you can use fan_count field

Comment: The `/search` endpoint is gone. You need to use `/pages/search?q=XXX&fields=fan_count`

Answer (score 5):

I construct my API query like this, and it allows me to fetch a one shot query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?fields=comments.limit(25).summary(true),likes.limit(25).summary(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

the api has changed. new field name is 'fan count'.

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID?fields=fan_count

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, I found a simple solution.

I found you can get the number of likes a page has with Facebooks Graph API accessing the url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{page-id}?fields=fan_count&access_token={user-access-token}
```

You can curl it for the same result.

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{page-id}?fields=fan_count&access_token={user-access-token}"
```

*(replace `page-id` and `user-access-token`, with your own)*