# How to get Likes Count with one graphi api call /home with all default fields for each post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

The solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351526/465974
makes use of fields keyword

Is there a way to get the the likes count via likes.summary(true) or some other way with graphi api call /me/home 
but without restricting it to fields 
seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351526/337227 solution ?

Comment: As far as I recall, FQL and/or the graph API don't allow you to use `select *` syntax in queries. You can `select every, field, listed, in, the, api, documentation`, though.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use fields? Just curious.

Comment: I wanted to mention it in the question but left it. Each post seem to have varied number of fields. I would like to preserve data /home returns by default for the moment in addition to the like count. Otherwise it's too tedious a task to reconstruct that response data with fields for each post.

Comment: A comment in other stackoverflow post says sometimes api call doesn't really return same fields by default all the time. It's not consistent enough but it's fine for now

Comment: That is because not all posts are of the same type, and therefore also do not always contain the same fields... And, IMHO, what you want to achieve is not possible, because either you specify fields (which you have to if you want summary info), or you don't (but then you can't use summary because it's not a standard field)

Comment: I agree that not all posts are of same type. Hence the problem. 
Yeah, specify fields to get it or it's not possible. It makes sense.  So I ended up making one call for default info. and another one with likes summary field only. It's fast enough for now luckily.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible by design as fields need to be specified for summary info as mentioned in comments to the question above