# Facebook get number of likes on custom object without login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using og.likes to like custom object from my app, with the help of Facebook-iOS sdks. I am able to like object and also read the like.

Now I want to know if there is any way in graph API that, I can show total number of likes on an object to a user who is not logged in to our app via Facebook ? i.e without access token

Comment: do you want the like count of a post in facebook?

Comment: No, I have made a custom object via object browser. I have object id's , now I just want to get number of likes on that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got Response from Facebook Team :

> Since Graph API v2.0, all requests to the API require an access token.
>   You can proxy this request through a web-server and use your app
>   access token for example.
>
> You could as well make the request from your app by shipping your app
>   access token with the app, but I highly advise against this as the app
>   token should be kept secret.
>
> Please note that the SDK does not support using the app access token
>   for security reasons. So you have to write your own networking code to
>   fetch this data.

Answer (score 1):

**As per FB developer docs:-**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes

*It is mentioned that you need the same permissions required to view the parent object are required to view likes on that object, means an user access token with read_stream permission is required.*

**NOTE:**
But if a user want to get the no of likes for Facebook page or profile or object , then it can be easily done by this:-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/< your object id>/
```

Then you will receive json response with Like Count:-

```
{
 "id": "12345",
 "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/MY iOS Page/102445859460201",
 "likes": 150,
 "type": "page"
 }
```

Code:-

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/"+ObjectID)
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

 NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response:NSURLResponse!, data:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        // Fetch the data
       var jsonDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
        let likesCount = jsonDictionary["likes"] as? String 

  }
```

Comment: I give you a reference
http://www.espncricinfo.com/bangladesh-v-pakistan-2015/content/player/41434.html

Here we can see number of likes on player without any login, is it possible with iOS-SDK ?

Comment: Have to dig more for that, but in case of iOS i don't think it is certainly possible.

Comment: Thank you, I am also looking for confirmation somewhere

Comment: With this code FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"https://graph.facebook.com/{myobject-id}/"
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

I am still getting message "An access token is required to request this resource"

Comment: You cannot use FBSDKGraphRequest it will need user permission, you have send graph url request through NSURL and you will get the specified response. check my updated answer @Haris

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77680/discussion-between-haris-and-vizllx).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from

[How to get Likes Count when searching Facebook Graph API with search=xxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755753/how-to-get-likes-count-when-searching-facebook-graph-api-with-search-xxx)

Here in this link it's not the exact solution but i have tried my way and unfortunately it worked for me, and i am quite satisfied with it, still using it in my  application.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/{Object-id}?fields=likes.summary(true)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I have modified my answer Mr.@MayankJain please take a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an access token, no need to login any user, you can generate an APP Access token to get that info .

```
jQuery.get("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token", {
       'grant_type': "client_credentials",
        'client_id': "000000000000000",
        'client_secret': "0000000000000000000000000000000000"
   }, function (data) {
       // data is the app access token you will need for calling graph api
   });
```

Thats more complicated but solves the necessity to login the user to get public informations from the graph .