# How to set flag in Facebook Graph call in Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes/) of Facebook states:

> total_count --> Total number of people who liked. This is only returned when the > flag summary=true is set.

But how do I set such a flag (summary = true) in the following call:

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{object-id}/likes",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

(I want to know which code to use to get the JSON response with the total number of likes, not just what the url with a flag would look like.)

Comment: Take a look at this answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755753/how-to-get-likes-count-when-searching-facebook-graph-api-with-search-xxx

Comment: Thanks Jp, but those answers only show urls, how do I use those in Android?

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
/{object-id}/likes
```

With

```
/{object-id}/likes?summary=1
```