# FACEBOOK API: Get likes of particular post on page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get likes on post on the page: "The Jungle Book"

I am able to get the likes of the page using url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/" + pageId + "?fields=likes&access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I have read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes) 
and find that i will get the likes(total count) of the post only returned when the flag `summary=true` is set
The response should look like this

```
{
   "likes": <somecount>,
   "id": "151505938209071_1507814655911519"
}
```

I am able to get the likes on page but not able to get total number of likes on the particular post on that page.
Can anyone help me regarding how I should set the URL or is there any other way to do it.

Comment: who has down voted my post and can you explain the reason?

Answer (score 0):

From what you described it sounds like it should be like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/" + pageId + "?fields=likes&summary=true&access_token=" + ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The above is your existing URL with `summary=true` in between the `fields=likes` and `access_token` parameters

---

However you may be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18351526/5971390)

Quote:

> Couldn't find this in the documentation but multiple calls to the API are not necessary. You can use summary when querying a feed or multiple posts. Specify this in the fields parameter.
>
> ```
> https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)
> ```
>
> This will return a response like this.
>
> ```
> {
>   "data": [
>     {
>       ....
>       "summary": {
>         "total_count": 56
>       }
>       ...
>     }, 
>     {
>       ....
>       "summary": {
>         "total_count": 88
>       }
>       ...
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```
>
> This will be much faster than making individual requests for each object just to get the number of comments or likes.

Comment: Actually by doing this , i will get the names and id of people who liked that post but i need the total count of people who liked that post...e.g.
{
   "likes": 867839,
   "id": "151505938209071"
}

Comment: I can count but it will be unnecessary overhead... i will do that in worst case but if there's a thing exists from which i can get total count from API then it will be great

Comment: Yes @Tim but its giving response like this:
{
   "data": [
      
   ]
}
here is my url link](https://graph.facebook.com/151505938209071_1507694925923492/feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true))....
The real post has 1.2k likes

Comment: @ojas What about `https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?summary=true&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX` where it is `likes` instead of `feed`

Comment: Exception is coming while trying with above url:
Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"?\".\" at character 5: likes?summary=true