# Getting a list of people who liked a post on my Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am trying to write a quick script that would help me pick up random people who liked a post on my page for an award (your typical giveaway).

So far I have been trying to get used to the FB API, so I am using Facebook Graph Explorer. I have managed to generate a Page token (I am the admin of the group) and tried to get some information about the posts on the Page

```
{page-id}/posts?fields=id,message,created_time,shares,likes{name}&limit=2
```

The response, however, misses the `likes` key, and on the left hand side where you can add the fields (graph explorer new UI), `likes` becomes greyed out. All other keys are returned as requested.

I haven't found any mention of the depreciation of this field for the page owners. Do I need any additional credentials?

Comment: Why do you have `{name}` in there? According to FB API docs: `Only aggregated counts using 'total_count' with the 'summary' parameter are available for Post likes.` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/object/likes

Comment: @Ashley, `name` was a suggested "sub-field" by the explorer. I have tried removing the `name` field but it didn't change the output

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking that it's because you have targeted "posts" instead of your page or a single post - the list of posts belonging to your page probably don't have any likes linked to them. EDIT - nevermind, I'm stumped, sorry! Maybe this can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755753/how-to-get-likes-count-when-searching-facebook-graph-api-with-search-xxx

Comment: @Ashley thank you for your suggestions! that post is from 2013... the API has changed 100500 times since then